# get product category path

Tags: catalog, design

for designing purposes I need to retrieve the product category path of each single product. I was able to retrieve the category path and explode the first level using the following code in catalog/product/list.phtml:

```
<?php $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
<?php $exp = explode("/", $currentCat->getPath());?>
```

on the other hand I tried to retrieve category path of each product display in search results in order to display different colors for each product based on their main category but with no good results.

any help will be appreciated. brgds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will give you an array starting with the root category (id: 1), then the stores root category and then the path down to the category your product is in.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load([id])->getCategory();
$path = explode('/', $category->getPath());
```

How ever, this is quite a 'heavy' piece of code just for design purposes.
You might be better of extending the product collection in the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` class, method `_getProductCollection` joining the `catalog_category_entity` table to the collection query and adding the `path` field to the select fields

Comment: @sander-manguel thank you.. interesting approach. i will do that. brgds

Comment: @s_h : Could u pls explain, how you did this.

Comment: @JeevaRathinam it only works in category / product page. you put that code in the top of the file, and then you use $category in your code. thats it.

Comment: how can i get the ids from the category path?

Comment: please help me in this question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266825/how-to-set-the-category-ids-to-a-products-from-category-path

Answer (score 2):

To get path from Root catalog

```
public function getCategoryPath($sku)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

    $pathArray = array();
    $collection1 = $product->getCategoryCollection()
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToSelect('path')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');


    foreach($collection1 as $cat1){            
        $pathIds = explode('/', $cat1->getPath());            
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $pathIds));

        $pahtByName = '';
        foreach($collection as $cat){                
            $pahtByName .= '/' . $cat->getName();
        }

        $pathArray[] = $pahtByName;

    }

    return $pathArray;
}
```

Comment: How can i run above code?

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to find product categories for breadcrumbs when landing to product page outside site. (when `if ($category = $this->getCategory())` fails)

`$cate` is last category product was found in and you can use category functions to get path.

> magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php

Add where product is found if coming from somewhere else than category

Needs FIX: TODO: check if product has category before looping!

```
if(empty($path)) {
    if ($this->getProduct()) {
        $collection =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds()));
        $categories = array();
        $cate = "";
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $cate = $category;
            $pathInStore = $category->getPathInStore();
            $pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $pathInStore));
        }
        $categories = $cate->getParentCategories();
        if($categories) {
        foreach($pathIds as $categoryId) {
                $path['category'.$categoryId] = array(
                    'label' => $categories[$categoryId]->getName(),
                    'link' => $this->_isCategoryLink($categoryId) ? $categories[$categoryId]->getURL() : ''
                );
        }}
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answers that helped me to accomplish this.